# Is countability absolute over supertransitive models of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

It is known that countability is not absolute, for Skolem paradox shows that $\mathcal P(\omega)$ can be countable [externally speaking] in some models, while not in others. However, it appears to me that this won't be the case if we restrict models to be [supertransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class) [transitive sets in which all subsets of all elements in them are in them], since a bijection between two sets is a subset of a Cartesian product between them and models of $\sf ZFC$ are closed under Cartesian products.

I have two questions

1. Is the countability of a set absolute over supertransitive models of $\sf ZFC$?
2. If so, what are examples of other properties that are absolute over supertransitive models of set theory but not over transitive models of set theory?

Comment: Well, how does a supertransitive model look like?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you mean how does a supertransitive model of $\sf ZFC$ looks like? I don't know what do you exactly mean? It looks like a supertransitive set that satisfy ZFC.

Comment: Asaf's comment is closer to a hint rather than a question, at least for me. More hint: remind the definition of $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @HanulJeon, didn't get your hint either.

Comment: are you hinting that it looks like a Grothendieck universe؟

Comment: If $M$ is supertransitive and $\alpha\in M$ is an ordinal, then $V_\alpha\subseteq M$. You can show it by induction on $M$. Can you see from the previous claim that $M=V_\kappa$ for some ordinal $\kappa$?

Comment: @HanulJeon, yes what's the problem with that? this ordinal $k$ cannot be countable, and possibly even (not sure of that) cannot be accessible. So it ought to be a Grothendieck universe. Anyhow, this might answer the first question, but what about the second? Possibly I got things wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Such $\kappa$ is known as a *worldly cardinal*. You may google it to get its properties.

Comment: @HanulJeon, Oh yes, correct. When I said a Grothendieck universe I meant the model, but its ordinal index would be a worldly cardinal.